# Как закрыть модальное диалоговое окно?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Задача вывести html код в Google таблице для проигрывания музыки, и чтобы через несколько секунд этот код закрывался. Пока сделал так:
*Сам скрипт*

```
 function showDialog() {
   var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Win')
     .setWidth(4).setHeight(3);

   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Победа');
 }
```

Он открывает следующее модальное окно:
*Win.html*

```
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <audio id="player" autoplay>
    <source src="http://pesochnica.tk/cut.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Ваш браузер не поддерживает аудио элементы.
  </audio>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
    google.script.host.close();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Суть в том, что не получается реализовать паузу. Если в коде оставляю только `google.script.host.close();`, то окно отлично закрывается сразу после загрузки.
А при попытке добавить любой из следующих вариантов приводят к тому, что оконо просто остаётся висеть.

```
Utilities.sleep(5000);

Thread.sleep(5000);

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать setTimeout  (https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)

Comment: ничего не дало, также остаётся висеть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так получится:

**Code.gs**

```
function doSomething()
{
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
    Logger.log('I was called!');
}
```

**Win.html**

```
<html><head><base target="_top"></head>
<body>
    <audio id="player" autoplay>
        <source src="http://pesochnica.tk/cut.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Ваш браузер не поддерживает аудио элементы.
    </audio>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {    
        google.script.run
                .withSuccessHandler(closeDialog)
                .doSomething()
    };

    window.closeDialog = function()
    {
        google.script.host.close();
    };
    </script>
</body></html>
```

**Документация (на английском):**

[Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run). Client-side API

Comment: мне кажется, что он почему то не хочет работать с паузой. в исходном виде остаётся висеть, но лог записывает. Если стереть Utilities.sleep(5000); то после загрузки сразу закрывается.

Comment: @ПавелСергеевич,тогда перенесите строку `Utilities.sleep(5000);` на самый верх в `window.onload`. И отпишитесь тут.

Comment: перенёс, тоже самое, но теперь лог не записал, в смысле "I was called!" при этом пишет, что [18-06-01 06:08:14:230 PDT] Выполнение завершено за 0,054 сек.

Comment: @ПавелСергеевич,тогда перенесите строку `Utilities.sleep(5000);` в `doSomething()`. И отпишитесь тут.

Comment: Отлично, заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: @ПавелСергеевич, если мой ответ(НЕ сообщения под ним) вас устраивает, то пометьте его галочкой.

Comment: Я ждал, пока в ответе откорректируешь

Answer (score 1):

Если коротко, то

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      google.script.host.close();
    }, 5000);
  };
</script>
```

В общем случае, есть два варианта решения задачи: 1) установить колбэк, который сработает после вычислений на клиенте, 2) закрыть окно после рачетов на сервере.

### Вариант 1

Требует только код на клиенте. В примере используется `setTimeout`

```
  window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      google.script.host.close();
    }, 5000);
  };
```

### Вариант 2

Требует код и на клиенте и на сервере. В примере используется `Utilites.sleep()` для отложенного действия

#### сервер

```
function setServerTimeout(milliseconds){
  Utilities.sleep(milliseconds);
}
```

#### клиент

```
window.onload = function() {
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function() {
      google.script.host.close();
    })
    .setServerTimeout(5000);
};
```

Листинг рабочей програмы с примером https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/10ea6ecf35f17f9340906714a9f7f714